# IntelijIDEA не видит packages в том же модуле, в котором расположен основной файл

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, package

Суть проблемы: пытаюсь начать разработку игры в IntelijIDEA c фреймворком libGDX, сначала пытался создать необходимые классы и пакеты в модуле Core, в нём не было варианта создания package вообще, классы создавались только пустые и read-only, попробовал создать отдельный модуль - там отлично создаются классы и пакеты, но при компиляции он просто не видит пакеты, даже те, которые в том же модуле. 
[image: Как видите, имя пакета написано корректно и пакет находится в том же модуле, ошибки которые не видно вполне понятные, java просто ругается на использованиетех методов и переменных, которые не импортировались]
Как видите, имя пакета написано корректно и пакет находится в том же модуле, ошибки которые не видно вполне понятные, java просто ругается на использованиетех методов и переменных, которые не импортировались

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался в проблеме не совсем так, как подразумевается в вопросе: решил всё же попробовать делать через Android Studio [потому что баг, который мешал мне делать через неё, имеет решение на английской версии stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662171/androidstudio-exception-when-starting-android-in-a-libgdx-project?rq=1). Но эксперимента ради попробовал в Android Studio те же конструкции - модули и пакеты видит отлично, скорее всего у меня были какие-то проблемы с установкой/настройкой IntelliJIDEA, думаю проблема именно в установке или настройке, а не в IntelliJIDEA.